# deploy with capistrano using a pem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, amazon-ec2, capistrano

We have a EC2 instance, and our capistrano setup requires ssh.  To connect through ssh normally, I use a .pem file for connecting to the server.  how do I utilize this .pem file when using capistrano to deploy?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In `deploy.rb` set these configuration values:

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
ssh_options[:auth_methods] = ["publickey"]
ssh_options[:keys] = ["/path/to/key.pem"]
```

For Capistrano 3 use:

```
set :pty, true
set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: true,
  auth_methods: %w[publickey],
  keys: %w[/path/to/key.pem]
}
```

Comment: okay, I had all those but "publickey"...  So now I'm getting this error:  Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back

Comment: do you have a public key at server?

Comment: is there a way to have capistrano be verbose in its output?

Comment: You have to use:
ssh_options[:auth_methods] = ["publickey"]
to avoid NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "publickey":String error

Comment: You won't get a file-not-found error if the keyfile is not found, so double check the path to the key.

Comment: in Capistrano 3.10 I get ```NameError: undefined local variable or method `default_run_options' for main:Object```; see other answer for Capistrano 3 syntax

Comment: TylerJones `:ssh_options, { verbose: :debug }` will give you verbose output

Answer (score 39):

for capistrano 3 the syntax is somewhat different

```
set :pty, true

set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: true,
  auth_methods: ["publickey"],
  keys: ["/path/to/key.pem"]
}
```